# Contribute Form on Multiple WP sites

Tags: wordpress

Total noob here.

My client has installed CIVI on their Wordpress Site, Site 1, using the CIVICRM WP plugin which they are using to collect contributions. They have three other WP sites, different servers, where they'd like to collect contributions using the same database as Site 1.

Is this possible? If so, what is the best way to go about this? Is there a way to embed the CIVI contribute form on other sites?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 6):

Check out remote form. 
https://github.com/progressivetech/net.ourpowerbase.remoteform
I use it on my WordPress site. It's very clean and nice.
If this answer helped please mark this as answered. 
Thank you.